# Prometheus Scrape Error - "INVALID" is not a valid start token

Tags: prometheus

I am using https://github.com/danielqsj/kafka_exporter to get some metrics around kafka brokers. I can view metrics using browser on `https://abc/svc/kafka/metrics`

But get following error on Prometheus scrape targets:

```
level=warn ts=2020-10-19T19:39:47.645Z caller=scrape.go:930 component="scrape manager" scrape_pool=kafka-metrics target=http://kafka-metrics:9308/svc/kafka/metrics msg="append failed" err="\"INVALID\" is not a valid start token"
```

**Config file**

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'kafka-metrics'
    metrics_path: /svc/kafka/metrics
    static_configs:
    - targets: [kafka-metrics:9308]
```

Comment: You may need to add `scheme: https` (and perhaps certs|auth to the scrape config) because Prometheus defaults to http. See [link](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config). Also, you refer to the endpoint as `abc` and then `kafka-metrics`. Are these both DNS aliases for the server?

Comment: Looks like I didn't have to provide metrics_path in scrape config and increase scrape_timeout to 15s. Now it is working. ```kafka-metrics``` is the name of kubernetes pod hosting this metrics.

Comment: Ah! Glad you solved it